# How to record audio on android wear? Works on phone, not on watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-audiorecord

This application works on an Android phone, but when it is running on an Android Wear watch, it crashes after pressing the record button.
Can someone post example code for an audio recording app?

Here is the current code showing my progress so far.

The java Activity:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.provider.*;


public class WearableActivity extends Activity {
    private Button play;
    private Button record;
    private Button stop;
    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wearable);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);
        //stop.setEnabled(false);
        // play.setEnabled(false);


        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);



        record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    myAudioRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                    // make somthing
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    // make somthing
                }

                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAudioRecorder.stop();
                myAudioRecorder.release();
                myAudioRecorder = null;
                record.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Recorder successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // make something
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

wearable.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="record"
        android:id="@+id/record" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="play1"
        android:id="@+id/play" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.Zer0">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
        <activity
            android:name=".WearableActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

(I only added the following lines because it wouldn't let me submit the edit without them...)

Should I try a completely different approach, or can the phone app be transformed in a way that will work on the watch?

Comment: Hey thank you, both options are okey for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It records an audio using the wear microphone and then plays it.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearSpeakerSample

This is the apk built:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z6lwVoWh89gbGz43c_6PNPVS4Os6s4nu

I have put it also in the Google Play with a watchface:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jorc.android.wearable.watchface&hl=en

Comment: i tried on Android Studio, but i don't get it to work.

Comment: have a look above in a few hours form google play when the watch face includes the circle button, or simply use the apk I shared in the answer.

Comment: hey thank you so much, it is so nice.
Finally it works. Please do not change your app right away, let me have a little more time to get it done like you. Thanksssssss a lotttttt :) niceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you can make the audio files save to the phone.accept as answer please.